# Javascript - Click checkbox even if clicking missing, clicking outside checkbox

Tags: javascript, css, button, checkbox

:EDIT: I have it figured out. Thanks!

I have a standard `<button>` checkbox in a `<form>` that I'd like the user to be able to select even if they miss the box by a few pixels.

I'm nowhere near good enough with JS to know how to do this.

Been scouring for a half hour now, don't know what to type to get the results I want.

Comment: This is perfect, if I can put the checkbox inside the CSS block. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72770859/how-to-check-uncheck-checkbox-by-clicking-outside-specific-block

Answer (score 0):

You could just associate the input element with a label and give that a bit of padding.

This snippet puts the input as a child of the label.

```css
label {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox"></label>
```

Comment: Yep, figured that out. Thanks!